# Facing slowness on executing selenium script through Jenkins(remotely) on IE11 browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, iedriverserver, selenium-remotedriver

I am facing slowness on trying to execute my selenium script remotely on IE11
However, this is comparatively working fine with local execution

Selenium version: 3.141
IE driver: 3.14.0

I am working on a healthcare project and the supported browser is IE. Please suggest how to fix this problem?

Capabilities:

```
    private static WebDriver getInternetExplorerDriver(String driverpath) {
        if (driverpath.endsWith(".exe")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", driverpath);
        } else {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", driverpath + "IEDriverServer.exe");
        }
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        capabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, false);
        capabilities.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
        capabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", true);

        return new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
    }
```

Comment: Which version of `IEDriverServer.exe` are you using?  64 or 32-bit?

Comment: 64 bit IE driver. Also, my system OS is 64 bit

Comment: When you using IE 64 bit driver, you may meet the slow executing. You could try to use 32 bit. Even you are working with 64 bit OS this 32 bit IE driver works every time. For more you may refer to: http://learn-automation.com/challenges-with-ie-browser-in-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Try the 32-bit version.  YMMV.